# How to clear events listeners in react after removing an element from the DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

The idea was to create a dropdown that listens to mouse clicks outside its elements then is destroyed.
I am able to have the effect I want however I am unable to clear events each time the  dropdown elements are destroyed
(After a couple of opening and closing the dropdown I am registering like ten clicks even if the dropdown is closed)
trying to familiarize with react so your help is appreciated

My try,
calling the component

```
RequestDropDown.create(row.id).show({
      room_id: row.id,
      setTheState: this.setTheState
    });
```

creating the element on click

```
class RequestDropDown extends Component {
  static create(props = {}) {
    const containerElement = document.createElement('div');
    containerElement.classList.add('RequestDropDown_container');
    document.getElementById(`table_dots_btn_${props}`).after(containerElement);
    return render(
      <RequestDropDown createDropDownProps={props} />,
      containerElement
    );
  }
```

The constructor and methods

```
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.myRef = null;

    this.setmyRefRef = (element) => {
      this.myRef = element;
    };

    this.state = {
      isOpen: false,
      showDropDownProps: {},
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.handleClickOutside = this.handleClickOutside.bind(this);
    this.show = this.show.bind(this);
  }
  componentWillMount() {
     document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClick, false);

  }

  componentWillUnMount() {
    window.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClick, false);
  }

  handleClick= (e)=> {
      if(this.myRef.contains(e.target)) {
          console.log('you clicked inside')
          return;
      }
      this.handleClickOutside()
  }

  handleClickOutside= async () =>{
    console.log('the click is  outside');
    this.myRef = null;
    var element = await document.getElementsByClassName('RequestDropDown_container');
    if (element.length == 0) {
        return
    }
    await element[0].parentNode.removeChild(element[0]); // tried this too    unmountComponentAtNode(element[0]);
    this.setState({
        isOpen: false
    })
  }


  async show(props = {}) {

    await this.setState({ isOpen: true, room_id: props.room_id, setTheState: props.setTheState });

  }
```

the render

```
  render() {
    const { setTheState } = this.state;
    console.log(this.myRef)

    return (this.state.isOpen === true ?
      <div id="drop_down_node" ref={this.setmyRefRef}>
        <div class="confirm_modal_content">
          <div className="dropdown-content">
            <a>Room settings</a>
            <a onClick={setTheState}>standard room</a>
            <a

            // onClick={() => handleReject(row)}
            >
              deluxe room
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> : null
    );
  }
}

export default RequestDropDown;
```

Comment: componentWillMount() is deprecated, please use componentDidMount()

Comment: When you use React, don't mess with the DOM using getElementsByClassName and removeChild

Comment: Tried changing it, no sucess @HermitCrab , Please I am open to suggestions that was my try, also My only option is to attach the component where I need it

Comment: I also noticed that you attach your eventListener to document and then you remove it from window. You have to remove it from the same element (ie document)

Comment: I have tried that too bro @HermitCrab , that was just me going crazy

Answer (score 0):

```js
componentWillMount() {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClick, false);

}

componentWillUnMount() {
    document.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClick, false);
}
```